# Java exception handling: Missing return type

Tags: java, exception, return

I'm relatively new to Java and I have run into an issue which I'm unable to figure a way to get around.

Here is my code:

```
// Ex2 is a child of Ex1
public T method(someType someArg) throws Ex1{
  try{
    someFunc() // Throws both Ex1 and Ex2
    T ret = someOtherFunc() //Throws Ex1, cannot declare/initialize ret outside
    return ret
  } catch(Ex2){
    //do something
  } catch(Ex1){
    //do something
  } 

}
```

Now java complains about missing return type whereas it DOES NOT complain when I remove Ex2 handling/catching.

Comment: Exceptions are something that happens at runtime. What you have are *compile errors*.

Answer (score 3):

Your method must return a `T`, you could add `return null;` as the last statement. Or, modify the visibility (and default value of) `ret` like

```
public T method(someType someArg) throws Ex1{
  T ret = null;
  try{
    someFunc(); // Throws both Ex1 and Ex2
    ret = someOtherFunc();
  } catch(Ex2){
    //do something
  } catch(Ex1){
    //do something
  } 
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: But the code compiles when I remove the catch block for Ex2, handling just Ex1. I want to understand this behavior.

Comment: @FayazAhmed Then it was a great idea to hide the code inside these catch blocks. But generally speaking: you need a `return` statement or abort the method by throwing an exception. `catch Ex2` doesn't the latter, so it needs a `return`. `catch Ex1` either re-throws the exception, or throws a new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are merely catching the exceptions and not throwing any exceptions after handling/logging them, then the method is handling the errors correctly but not returning anything (boom, compilation error).

If you are going to handle the exceptions yourself, you need to either return a null (or other reasonable invalid value) or re-throw the caught exception.

If you are going to rethrow an exception (other than ex1), make sure you add it to the method signature

For example:

```
// Ex2 is a child of Ex1
public T method(someType someArg) throws Ex1{
  try{
    someFunc() // Throws both Ex1 and Ex2
    T ret = someOtherFunc() //Throws Ex1, cannot declare/initialize ret outside
    return ret;

  } catch(Ex2 ex2){        
    // either re-throw the exception (or return null instead)
    throw ex2;

  } catch(Ex1 ex1){        
    // or return a null value (you can re-throw the exception instead)
    return null;
  } 
  // you can also return null here if you want to catch/handle both exceptions separately but want to return null in either case
  // return null;
}
```